# Using JOIN with DISTINCT and prioritize one table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to combine data from 2 tables.
Those 2 tables both contain data from the same sensor (lets say a sensor that measures CO2 with 1 entry per 10 minutes).

The first table contains validated data. Let's call it `station1_validated`. The 2nd table contains raw data. Let's call this one `station1_nrt`.

While the raw-data table contains live data, the validated table contains only data points that are at least 1 month old. (It needs some time to validate those data and to control it manually afterwards, this happens only once every month).

**What I am trying to do now** is to combine the data of those 2 tables to display live data on a website. However when validated data is available it should prioritize that data point over the raw data-point.

The relevant columns for this are:

- timed [bigint(20)]: Contains the datetime as a unix timestamp in milliseconds from 1.1.1970
- CO2 [double]: Contains the measured concentration of CO2 in ppm (parts per million)

I wrote this basic SQL:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
        timed, CO2, '2' tab
    FROM
        station1_nrt
    WHERE
        TIMED >= 1386932400000
            AND TIMED <= 1386939600000
            AND TIMED NOT IN (SELECT 
                timed
            FROM
                station1_nrt
            WHERE
                CO2 IS NOT NULL
                    AND TIMED >= 1386932400000
                    AND TIMED <= 1386939600000) UNION SELECT 
        timed, CO2, '1' tab
    FROM
        station1_validated
    WHERE
        CO2 IS NOT NULL
            AND TIMED >= 1386932400000
            AND TIMED <= 1386939600000) a
ORDER BY timed
```

This does not work correctly as it selects only those data points where both tables have an entry.
However I want to do this with a `JOIN` now as it would be much faster. However I don't know how to a JOIN with a DISTINCT (or something similar) with prioritizing a table. Could someone help me out with this (or explain it?)

Comment: Are datapoints related by `TIMED`? I.e. does `TIMED` relate a record in the nrt table with one in the validated table?

Comment: yes, the values inside `timed` are the same per data-point on both tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Jim, @valex, @ExplosionPills
I managed to write a SQL select that emulates a `FULL OUTER JOIN` (as there is no FULL JOIN in MySQL) and returns the value of the validated data if it exists. If no validated data is available it will return the raw value

So this is the SQL I am using now:

```
SET @StartTime  = 1356998400000;
SET @EndTime    = 1386546000000;

SELECT
    timed,
    IFNULL (mergedData.validatedValue, mergedData.rawValue) as value
FROM
((SELECT 
    from_unixtime(timed / 1000) as timed,
    rawData.NOX as rawValue,
    validatedData.NOX as validatedValue
FROM
    nabelnrt_bas as rawData
    LEFT JOIN nabelvalidated_bas as validatedData using(timed)
WHERE 
    (rawData.timed > @StartTime
    AND rawData.timed < @EndTime)
    OR (validatedData.timed > @StartTime
    AND validatedData.timed < @EndTime)

) UNION (
SELECT 
    from_unixtime(timed / 1000) as timed,
    rawData.NOX as rawValue,
    validatedData.NOX as validatedValue
FROM
    nabelnrt_bas as rawData
    RIGHT JOIN nabelvalidated_bas as validatedData using(timed)
WHERE 
    (rawData.timed > @StartTime
    AND rawData.timed < @EndTime)
    OR (validatedData.timed > @StartTime
    AND validatedData.timed < @EndTime)
)
ORDER BY timed DESC) as mergedData
```

Answer (score 3):

You haven't mentioned if there exist records in `station1_validated` which don't exist in `station1_nrt` so I use `FULL JOIN`. If all rows from `station1_validated` exist in `station1_nrt` then you can use LEFT JOIN instead.

Something like this

```
SELECT IFNULL(n.timed,v.timed) as timed,
       CASE WHEN v.timed IS NOT NULL THEN v.CO2 ELSE n.CO2 END as CO2,
       CASE WHEN v.timed IS NOT NULL THEN '1' ELSE '2' END as tab

FROM station1_nrt as n
FULL JOIN station1_validated as v ON n.timed=v.timed AND v.CO2 IS NOT NULL
    WHERE
        ( n.TIMED between 1386932400000 AND 1386939600000
          or 
          v.TIMED between 1386932400000 AND 1386939600000
        )
        AND 
        (n.CO2 IS NOT NULL OR v.CO2 IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Looks good to me, but I think `(n.CO2 IS NOT NULL OR v.CO2 IS NOT NULL)` should be `AND` instead of `OR`. Also, you can then get rid of `AND v.CO2 IS NOT NULL` in `ON` clause. Also, don't forget the `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @valex I managed to achieve this with a rather long SQL, check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can join and then use `IF`s in the fields to choose the validated values if they exist. Something like:

```
SELECT
IFNULL(s1val.timed,s1.timed) AS timed,
IFNULL(s1val.C02,s1.C02) AS C02,
2 AS 2,
IFNULL(s1val.tab,s1.tab) AS tab,
FROM 
station1_nrt s1
LEFT JOIN station1_validated s1val ON (s1.TIMED = s1val.TIMED)
WHERE
-- Any necessary where clauses
```

Comment: I am getting error message "invalid parameter count on function IFNULL": `IFNULL(s1val.timed, s1val.timed,s1.timed)`

Comment: @RononDex Whoops. Typo. Will fix.

Comment: I managed to achieve this with a rather long SQL, check my answer

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has an `IF` that would probably work for you.  You would have to select specific columns, though, but you could build the query programmatically.

```
SELECT
    IF(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) < FROM_UNIXTIME(nrt.TIMED),
        val.value,
        nrt.value
    ) AS value
    -- Similar for other values
FROM
    station1_nrt AS nrt
    JOIN station1_validated AS val USING(id)
ORDER BY TIMED
```

Note that the `USING(id)` is a placeholder.  Presumably there is some indexed column you can join the two tables on.

Comment: I just tried your statement. I am getting an error that it could not find the field 'val'.

Comment: @RononDex sorry, I forgot to alias the tables.  Still, you shouldn't run *exactly* what I have.  You need to figure out what it's doing so you can make necessary changes

Comment: I know that I have to adjust it. Actually in fact my tables have different names. Let me give it a try

Comment: I just tried it and it returns me 0 results. I think the problem is, that it only selects data points that are in both tables. However the validated-data table contains only data that is older than 1 month

Comment: @RononDex so you're saying that the month-old data is removed from `nrt`?

Comment: It does not get removed from nrt. However the problem is that we had been storing the live data in the database only for a few days till now, while we have much older validated data stored in the database. So yes, we only have live data for the last few days (while this is increasing of course), the validated data goes back far into the past

Comment: @ExplosionBills I managed to achieve this with a rather long SQL, check my answer